# the identity 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' (...), does not have permissions to create the App_Data subdirectory within the application root directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application that need to the authenticated user id, to be inserted into a table along with the form submitted.  I use the code below:

```
var userId = Int32.Parse((string) Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
```

But it give me the error:

```
Access denied creating App_Data subdirectory

Description: For security reasons, the identity 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' (under which this web application is running), does not have permissions to create the App_Data subdirectory within the application root directory. ASP.NET stores the Microsoft SQL Express Database file used for services such as Membership and Profile in the App_Data subdirectory of your application.
```

I am not creating anything.  I just want to get the UserId of the currently logged in user.  It works when I get the name, code below:

```
var userName = (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ? User.Identity.Name : "";
```

I need the UserId because that's what I use as foreign key constraint to the UserProfile table.

In the Create method of the controller, I assign it as:

```
serialnumber.UserId = userId;
...
db.SerialNumbers.Add(serialnumber);
```

How do I get the UserId of the current user?

Comment: But you are creating something, by trying to log in and creating a new user, you are creating a database under App_Data.  Your folder doesn't allow the default app pool to have permissions to do that.

Comment: I am inserting record to my table, SerialNumber table.  The statement `var userId = Int32.Parse((string) Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);` is only to get the value of the UserId.  This UserId will then be inserted into SerialNumber table.

Answer (score 0):

The default users setup in MVC uses a code-first with an application startup script to create a database.  This seems to be required (by default at least) regardless of whether you actually need it or not (I've run into similar scenarios with required database permissions even though it wasn't using the database: still needed the permissions).

You can jump into the Accounts model and EF stuff and wrangle around with it, but IMO it's easier just to allow the IIS account full permission on the root folder of your application directory.

Right click your app directory, Properties, Security, select the appropriate user/group from the list, edit, then grant full control:

[image]